# Return JSON with key-value pair

Tags: java

I use this code to generate response from REST endpoint:

```
if (result.hasErrors()) {
            List<String> errorsList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<FieldError> errors = result.getFieldErrors();
            for (FieldError error : errors ) {
                System.out.println("Validation error in field: " + error.getObjectName() 
                               + "! Validation error message: " + error.getDefaultMessage() 
                               + "! Rejected value:" + error.getRejectedValue());
                errorsList.add(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
            }

            return ResponseEntity.ok(new StringResponseDTO(errorsList));
        }
```

Object:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonTypeName("response")
public class StringResponseDTO {

    private String redirect;

    private List<String> errors;

    public StringResponseDTO(String redirect) {
        super();
        this.redirect = redirect;
    }

    public StringResponseDTO(List<String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    ......
}
```

Now I get this response:

```
{
  "response" : {
    "errors" : [ "expiration_year: must not be null", "default_transaction_type: must not be null"]
  }
}
```

I need to change it like this:

```
{
      "response" : {
        "errors" : [ "expiration_year": "must not be null", "default_transaction_type": "must not be null"]
      }
    }
```

Is there someway to archive his without added a lot of "" symbols?

Comment: `List<String> errors` should be `Map<String, String>`, but it will be converted into object, as json arrays do not support keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you expressed in the "wanted" result isn't valid.
What you can do is use Jackson (or GSON, depending on the library you're using) classes, for example

(Note, `objectMapper` is an instance of `ObjectMapper`)

```
public class StringResponseDTO {
    private String redirect;
    private TreeNode errors;

    public StringResponseDTO(final String redirect) {
        this.redirect = redirect;
    }

    public StringResponseDTO(final Collection<? extends FieldError> errors) {
        this.errors =
                errors.stream()
                      .collect(Collector.of(
                              objectMapper::createObjectNode,
                              (json, e) -> json.put(e.getField(), e.getDefaultMessage()),
                              (json, toMerge) -> {
                                  json.setAll(toMerge);
                                  return json;
                              }
                      ));
    }

    public String getRedirect() {
        return redirect;
    }

    public TreeNode getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
}
```

That will be serialized to

```
{
    "redirect": "...",
    "errors": {
        "field1": "err field1",
        "field2": "err field2",
        "field3": "err field3"
    }
}
```

---

Or, if you prefer, the usual `Map<String, String>` solution.

```
public class StringResponseDTO {
    private String redirect;
    private Map<String, String> errors;

    public StringResponseDTO(final String redirect) {
        this.redirect = redirect;
    }

    public StringResponseDTO(final Collection<? extends FieldError> errors) {
        this.errors =
                errors.stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                              FieldError::getField,
                              FieldError::getDefaultMessage
                      ));
    }

    public String getRedirect() {
        return redirect;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
}
```

Which will output the same thing

```
{
    "redirect": "...",
    "errors": {
        "field1": "err field1",
        "field2": "err field2",
        "field3": "err field3"
    }
}
```

---

It's up to you.

Comment: I get The constructor StringResponseDTO(Map<String,String>) is undefined

Comment: @PeterPenzov where di you see that constructor?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Collection means you still have to pass in the List<FieldError>, not a Map

Comment: I get this error at this line `return ResponseEntity.ok(new StringResponseDTO(errorsList));`

Comment: @PeterPenzov see comment above (Collection means you still have to pass in the List<FieldError>, not a Map)

Comment: @PeterPenzov btw, remove the "final var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();". It was a leftover.

Answer (score 1):

The `"` symbols are quotes, and they are necessary as part of the JSON specification. As for why your JSON is in a format you don't want, it has to do with your code here (and also in your corresponding `StringResponseDTO`):

```
errorsList.add(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
```

You are adding strings to a list. What you want is to create a list of objects, instead. Each object would contain a property and string value.

What you have proposed is not valid JSON:

```
{
  "response" : {
  "errors" : [ "expiration_year": "must not be null", "default_transaction_type": "must not be null"]
      }
}
```

What you need is this format instead (notice the object `{` symbols):

```
{
   "response" : {
   "errors" : [ {"expiration_year": "must not be null"}, {"default_transaction_type": "must not be null"}]
      }
}
```